# return count of rows and sum from the same model

Tags: python, django, django-models

Sorry for the unclear title...I donno how to put it right. Basically, I have the following model:

```
    class Items(models.Model):
       total=models.IntegerField()
```

Sample Data now is simply:

```
     1         10
     2         15
     3         90
     6         10
     9         20
```

I have totally 5 items with a total of 145. I tried the following but it failed cos it is grouping the id column which returns me a dictionary in the following strucutre:

```
    {"total_items":1,"items_worth":10, "total_items":2,"items_worth":15}
```

where as what I want is:

```
     {"total_items":5, "total_worth":145}
```

in SQL, it was ok:

```
    SELECT COUNT(id) as total_items,SUM(total) as total_worth
```

Whereas DJANGO adds,

```
   SELECT COUNT(id) as total_items,SUM(total) as total_worth FROM model GROUP BY id
```

This is my current Django Query:

```
   data=Items.Objects.all().annotate(total_items=Count('id'),total_worth=Sum('total')).values('total_items','total_worth')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Sum. Just use [`aggregation`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/aggregation/)

```
from django.db.models import Count, Min, Sum, Avg
data = Items.objects.aggregate(Sum('total'), Count('id'))
```

Sample output

```
{'total__sum': 145, 'id__count': 5}
```